# How to install exact specific redis version in Dockerfile Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: redis, dockerfile

I need to install redis 7.0.5 version in Dockerfile.

Below commands installing 7.0.7 version

```
curl https://packages.redis.io/gpg | apt-key add - && echo "deb https://packages.redis.io/deb $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list && apt-get update && apt-get install redis -y; \
```

I have tried below commands but it is installing latest version

```
curl https://packages.redis.io/gpg | apt-key add - && echo "deb https://packages.redis.io/deb $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list && apt-get update && apt-get install redis -y; \
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Distributions (and upstream) generally believer "newer is better" as more bugs are fixed, features added etc.  So _ex ante_ 7.0.7 is preferable over 7.0.5. If you still think you need 7.0.5 _exactly_ you could always build it from source. You can also try a service such as https://snapshot.debian.org/ which holds every version ever published in Debian (but the dependency mechanism is still setup for the _current_ builds).